# Extending Pyomo Constraint

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo, pulp

I am new to Pyomo and used Pulp for my model creation till now. I wanted to understand the procedural equivalent in Pyomo of steps I used to follow in Pulp to extend a constraint.

*Pulp Implementation:*

```
con = pulp.LpConstraintVar(name="Cons1", sense=pulp.LpConstraintEQ, rhs=200)
model.addConstraint(con.constraint)
```

In pulp this line of code will essentially create a empty constraint for me, which will look like this (I know will be infeasible if run at this stage, but won't run the code until cons is complete):

```
Cons1: 0 == 200
```

I can then add variables to this constraint based on my requirement. For example if we consider `x` is a variable to be added here, I can do this operation:

```
con.addVariable(x, 2)
```

It will result in me having extended (updated) the previous constraint to:

```
Cons1: 2x + 0 == 200
```

I can keep on calling addVariable to add as many variables I want inside multiple parts of code and it will work.

I wanted to understand how can I do similar thing in Pyomo, as this gives me better control over my constraint as compared to normal syntax->

```
model.Cons1= Constraint(expr = model.x*2 == 200)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a named expression (`Expression`) to facilitate this:

```py
>>> model = ConcreteModel()
>>> model.x = Var()
>>> model.Cons1_body = Expression(expr=0)
>>> model.Cons1 = Constraint(expr=model.Cons1_body == 200)
>>> model.Cons1_body += model.x * 2
>>> model.pprint()
1 Var Declarations
    x : Size=1, Index=None
        Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        None :  None :  None :  None : False :  True :  Reals

1 Expression Declarations
    Cons1_body : Size=1, Index=None
        Key  : Expression
        None :        2*x

1 Constraint Declarations
    Cons1 : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Lower : Body       : Upper : Active
        None : 200.0 : Cons1_body : 200.0 :   True

3 Declarations: x Cons1_body Cons1
```

The complexity here arises from the philosophy in Pyomo that expressions should be *immutable* - that is, once created, the structure of tree that represents the expression graph can't be changed.  This means that actions like replacing variables or adding terms requires creating a (partially) new expression graph.  The way this impacts Constraints is that Pyomo doesn't really have a native column generation API.  Instead, you would replace the Constraint expression with a new expression:

```py
model.Cons1 = Constraint(expr = model.x*2 == 200)
model.Cons1 = model.Cons1.expr.arg(0) + model.y * 3 == model.Cons1.expr.arg(1)
```

The named expression (`Expression`) component provides a structured way to break the expression immutability: named expressions behave like "pointers" when they are used in expressions, and the pointer is allowed to be changed without rebuilding the expression tree(s) that the named expression appear in.

Some notes:

- Pyomo doesn't (easily) support defining a constraint without any variables.  Attempting to create `Constraint(expr=0 == 200)` will result in an exception:

  ```
  ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for Constraint Cons1 with index
  None: ValueError: Invalid constraint expression. The constraint expression
  resolved to a trivial Boolean (False) instead of a Pyomo object. Please modify
  your rule to return Constraint.Infeasible instead of False.
  ```
- You can get something similar to  your "empty" constraint using the tuple notation, `Constraint(expr=(200, 0, 200))`:

  ```py
  >>> model.Cons2 = Constraint(expr=(200, 0, 200))
  >>> model.Cons2.pprint()
  Cons2 : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
      Key  : Lower : Body : Upper : Active
      None : 200.0 :  0.0 : 200.0 :   True
  ```
- Be careful with the "equality" form of the tuple notation, as Pyomo has no information to know if the "0" or the "200" should be the constraint body, and which should be the rhs, although the `.expr.arg(0)` and `.expr.arg(1)` are well-defined:

  ```py
  >>> model.Cons3 = Constraint(expr=(0, 200))
  >>> model.Cons3.pprint()
  Cons3 : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
      Key  : Lower : Body  : Upper : Active
      None :   0.0 : 200.0 :   0.0 :   True
  >>> model.Cons3.expr.arg(0)
  0
  >>> model.Cons3.expr.arg(1)
  200
  ```